# japanese characters show as boxes in chrome due to text-rendering: optimizelegibility;

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, internationalization, text-rendering

In my website I am using [Font-Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.com/Font-Awesome/) library. It applies a css attribute `text-rendering: optimizelegibility;` on header tags. This breaks my website when laguage is japanese.

As you can see in the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/urvNf/), boxes are shown when this property is used. I don't really understand what this property does, so is it safe to override it to auto?

Note:This property works fine in firefox but gives problem in google chrome.

Thanks for help :)

EDIT: This problem is specific to window-XP

I have also opened a issue on chrome site: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159391

Comment: working in my chrome http://imgur.com/9Afyv

Comment: @swapnesh which version are you using, my useragent is `"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4"`

Comment: my chrome Version- 22.0.1229.94

Comment: what abt your system?? i think its need up gradation now ;)

Comment: I see yours is window vista or 7, mine is XP, If this is a XP bug, then also i need it to be fixed, as we need to support it

Comment: check this link i think it will help u http://www.wikihow.com/Get-Japanese-Characters-%28Kanji,-Hiragana,-Katakana%29-on-Firefox  and also check settings under chrome settings tab for font http://imgur.com/MTrYu

Comment: @swapnesh, this is not a font problem, as you can see in this image http://imgur.com/huxCo japanese is rendered properly when the above property is auto. And also i confirm this problem is specific to XP(checked on 6 machines), can't replicate it on windows 7

Answer (score 2):

Font Awesome uses fontastic trickery that is based using fonts that contain iconic images in place of normal characters, in special fonts. This trickery mostly works, because the special fonts are served as downloadable fonts with wrong information about character support. But I don’t see how Font Awesome relates to the problem. I cannot see any CSS code related to headings in the CSS files in the Font Awesome package. It may indirectly affect headings, if you heading elements have `class` attributes coinciding with those used in Font Awesome. In that case, change the class names there.

And there is no `text-rendering` setting there either. I suspect that the setting comes from another source.

In any case, the [`text-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-rendering) property setting can safely be removed (or set to `auto`, the initial value). It is of typographic nature, and the *known* and somewhat documented effects relate to kerning and ligatures, which probably don’t apply to Japanese writing anyway. It may have other effects, and its specification is very vague. It is possible that in some context, Chrome might be trying to use rendering technology that fails in (some flavors of) Windows XP.

Testing your demo in a virtual Windows XP, which presumably corresponds to an old out-of-the box XP, Japanese characters are not displayed at all. No font seems to contain them. Different XP installations may have added fonts, such as Arial Unicode MS, which is shipped with MS Office, and then the problem changes.

Comment: Sry, by mistake i mentioned Font-Awesome, it is actually in bootstrap: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/type.less#L62

Comment: @ankur were you able to solve this issue as even i am facing the same in Chrome on windows xp.

Comment: @noobcode override css with any other values https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/text-rendering and it should work

Comment: @ankur : I do not have text rendering property set on my CSS. Do you suggest i declare this in my css? Another thing i noticed was any other japanese site such as yahoo.co.jp would not work on chrome on windows xp? Any suggestions?

Comment: @noobcode I had the problem due to  text-rendering property which was defined by some library(i don't remember the name). so i overrode it. And the site you mentioned is working on my google chrome window xp.

Comment: @ankur Thanks for your reply. I checked other japanese websites and it has the same issue. Could be that my chrome has some settings missing. Will look into it further. Thanks again.